# there is no attribute "data-over"

Tags: html

I get this error when I try to validate my page. I use dataover because it seems hard to roll over my image-menu bar in CSS. I also have a bit of java in beginning line of my code.

Im using the transitional doc type so thats good I guess... 
Help? :)

```
there is no attribute "data-over"
… data-out="images/nav/home_btn.png" data-over="images/nav/home_roll.png" /></a>
```

You have used the attribute named above in your document, but the document type you are using does not support that attribute for this element. This error is often caused by incorrect use of the "Strict" document type with a document that uses frames (e.g. you must use the "Transitional" document type to get the "target" attribute), or by using vendor proprietary extensions such as "marginheight" (this is usually fixed by using CSS to achieve the desired effect instead).

Comment: You need to use the HTML 5 doctype: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Oke, but when I do like now the validator gives me like 32 erros, and with the transitional only 5.. 2 because of the error above and 3 because the javascript.

So what to do?

Comment: Rewrite your code as valid HTML5! Look at the link to the HTML5 draft specification in my answer, that should help you understand what's valid and what's not.

Answer (score 3):

Custom data attributes are an [HTML5 feature](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes). It sounds to me like you're not using the HTML5 doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```